# Is it appropriate to use constants for dates?

Tags: php

I use dates throughout an app. Rather than calculating the dates I need each time I need them, I set them once in a constants file.

I.e. `define('NOW', date('Y-m-d'));`

Previously I used constants for things like file paths, etc. Does it make sense to load a bunch of dates like this, over, say, a single array of dates?

Comment: I personally think it's fine, but you might group them in classes

Comment: What if your script runs for 5 seconds (or longer) around midnight? Some dates could be wrong. I don't like it. And you have the format hardcoded.... `NOW` does not express that (I would expect a proper timestamp) and changing it later could introduce bugs. I don't like it. Just use `date` when you need it.

Comment: What are you trying to gain by using this? Has a profiler told you the date function is choke point? Is it important to you that all dates for a single run of a script are the same (as opposed to a date being the date a that specific time). You're asking us to do a cost-benefit analysis without knowing what benefits you expect. Personally, I don't see any benefits to storing dates instead of using `date()`, but as Yotam Omer says, if you want to, go for it.

Comment: I'm most motivated by readability in this specific use case, not so much performance. And while Wesley's point is well noted, I'm not concerned with crossing the midnight threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, **YOU CAN DO WHATEVER YOU WANT!** Using a constant for this matter will not generate any script error and your code should work just fine.

Longer answer:

Constants are there for you to store values that are not meant to be changed throughout the entire runtime - they are not limited to the scope of the current application run and usually used to store values that will not change over long(er) periods of time (such as database login details, certain application properties etc.). HOWEVER, if a certain value is relevant only for the current run and is meant to be kept unchanged, I don't see any problem with using a constant.

A point you need to take into consideration is that some scripts can run for a few seconds (in rare cases even longer), if your goal is to consider the entire action as "done when started" you're fine, however if you care about the actual time when the action was completed you should not use a constant.

Comment: Seems like a crummy idea IMO

Comment: @WesleyMurch I know it's not the most "textbook" use of constants however I cannot think of a real reason not to do it.